# Android KitKat webview width of the html page

Tags: android, html, css, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

The problem only appears on KitKat with the new WebView mechanism.

Basically I am loading 12 images, one after another in a row. I want the WebView to load all images on a row and auto zoom the webView to fir the entire row.

**How it works prior android 4.4**

- the images are loaded on the row and the zoom is made to fit the entire row. The user can scroll in and out

**How it works on 4.4**

- the images are wrapped, so I have the first image drawn and the next one is under it, not to its right

The html loads images like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, minimum-scale=0.3, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1"/>

<style type="text/css">
    body {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; float: left; white-space: nowrap;}

    .Image .Tile-0-0 {background: url(tiles/tile_0_0.png) no-repeat; width: 128px; height: 128px; float: left;}
.....

and then
<body>

<div class="Image">
    <div class="tile-0-0"></div>
    <div class="tile-1-0"></div>
    .......<br/>
```

Any ideas? My guess is that somehow I need to tell webview to fit the entire  row, not wrap on the device's width.

How could I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 4.4 (KitKat) has a completely different WebView (based on Chromium source) than previous Android versions. There is a [migration guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html) that describes common problems you might experience.

In your case the first thing I'd check is whether the HTML renders correctly in Chrome.

If it does, try setting targetSdk to 19 in your manifest (this disables some quirks) and see if that helps.

If it doesn't it might be a change in how CSS is interpreted/layout is performed between the two WebView implementations. Try fiddling with your CSS and see if that helps. [Using DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews) should make it simpler.

Another thing to look at is the viewport - see if the document.documentElement.clientWidth differs between the two versions. If it does then that's the reason it looks differently. If you're using wrap_contents height try using match_parent/a fixed value.

Comment: You were right, the page didn't render correctly on Chrome browser so after a bit of trial and error I have found that if I set the width:xxx px in style, the wrapping won't happen.